# Jenkins SVN on slaves

Tags: svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a jenkins server which I configured to use SVN 1.7 (Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Subversion->1.7).
I have a slave that i installed tortoiseSVN on, and added it the PATH variable in the slave machine.
When i run svn --version in the slave i see

```
 svn, version 1.7.18 (r1615261)
   compiled Aug  9 2014, 13:23:04

Copyright (C) 2014 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people; see the NOTICE
file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/
```

but when i run svn --version in jenkins job i get

```
  vn, version 1.6.12 (r955767)
   compiled Jun 21 2010, 16:00:59

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
```

the difference in the versions causes this error :

```
svn: The path '.' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
working copy.
```

How can I configure jenkins to use the correct SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you has 2 installations of SVN. One 1.7 and secodn - 1.6

Execute in job
    echo %PATH%
from jenkins job to see where 1.6 version can be installed.
(or use which svn, if you use Linux)

Then you can uninstall 1.6 or modify system PATH variable, so svn 1.7 will be in paths first.

Selection SVN version in Jenkins (Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Subversion) do not affect 'Command' build step. It affect 'Source Code Management', 'Triggers'

Comment: I see the 1.6 version in the %PATH%. it seems like the echo %path% from the machine is different than the one from the job.
I added C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin; at the start of the PATH system variable (through computer->Advanced system settings->Environment variables) but the job still doesn't show it when i run it in jenkins(unlike in the slave cmd echo %Path% that does show it).

Comment: I deleted the 1.6 folder entirely and now the jenkins job fails to find svn, even thought 1.7 is in the path in the slave and works fine in the slave.

Comment: Did you restart jenkins service after change PATH?

Comment: Restarting Jenkins and the slave did not help.
When I add Set PATH=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;%PATH% to the job it works but i don't want to do it that way

Comment: Check this: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27739 Possible you need recreate slave.